# Drawing polygon with Rstudio: error with boundaries

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I'm trying to make a polygon, I need the whole area to the left of the curve filled with color.

[image: curve] 
But I get the following error.

[image: polygon]
 I think there's a problem with the boundaties (or coordinates?) being wrong, but I have no idea how I could make it right. 
Here is my code:

```
    > head(sd_10_20)
  row  w         sd
1   1 26 0.59090909
2   2 12 0.27272727
3   3  6 0.13636364
4   4  4 0.09090909
5   5  4 0.09090909
6   6  4 0.09090909

 plot(sd_10_20$sd, sd_10_20$row, ylim = rev(range(50,510)), col='black', type='l', ylab='tiefe [mm]', xlab='surface density [-]')
polygon(c(sd_10_20$sd[1],sd_10_20$sd,sd_10_20$sd[length(sd_10_20$sd)]),c(50,sd_10_20$row,510),col='darkolivegreen', border = NA, ylim = rev(range(50,510)))
```

Comment: Upvote and mark answers as correct if they were useful and answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are drawing your polygon with incorrect starting and ending points. For `polygon` imagine you are drawing a shape without lifting up your pencil. Your start and end points get connected, and areas within `x` values and the line are colored in.

So to color the area under your points, anything `<x`, you need points at your minimum `y`, maximum `y`, and from outside of your graph (since `0` is your minimum, set it to `-1`  and see if that works) to all your `x` values. So using the data posted below, that would be `c(-1,sd_10_20$foo_sd,-1)` for your `x` values, and `c(min(sd_10_20$foo_row),sd_10_20$foo_row,max(sd_10_20$foo_row))` for your `y` values.

```
sd_10_20 <- data.frame(foo_row = c(1:500), foo_w = c(runif(500, 1, 26)), foo_sd = c(runif(500, 0, 1.4)))

plot(sd_10_20$foo_sd, sd_10_20$foo_row, ylim = rev(range(50,510)), col='black', type='l', ylab='tiefe [mm]', xlab='surface density [-]')
polygon(c(-1,sd_10_20$foo_sd,-1),c(min(sd_10_20$foo_row),sd_10_20$foo_row,max(sd_10_20$foo_row)),col='darkolivegreen', border = NA, ylim = rev(range(50,510)))
```

[image]